# Create a diagonal background image

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to create a diagonal background image as seen in the attached image. I can create a diagonal line using linear-gradient however as I have two different angles this didn't work.

[image: Example here]

Comment: You mean the third (the bottom-most) layer?

Comment: If @Harry is right, then create a rectangular div and play with CSS properties like transform and perspective. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_perspective1

Comment: @Harry Yes it would be the bottom most layer - should I be using a child div for the diagonal layer or can it be done with a parent div?

Comment: It can be done with a single `div` using multiple gradient layers but there are other alternates also - like using an SVG, a perspective rotated pseudo-element etc. I will try to cover a few in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Using Linear Gradients:**

This can be done using multiple background images and positioning them accordingly. In the snippet below I've used 3 different layers - one for the top angle (a triangle which is transparent for 50% and is colored for the rest), one for the middle which is essentially nothing but a solid colored rectangle, this is created using linear gradients as it is easier to control the dimensions of an image and finally one for the bottom angle (same approach as the top one but this has a different height and so different angle.)

The output is also responsive as you can see by hovering the element in the below snippet. In the 2nd `div`, I've set different colors for each image so that you can see how it is formed.

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 50%, lightblue 51%), linear-gradient(lightblue, lightblue), linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 50%, lightblue 51%);
  background-size: 100% 30px, 100% calc(100% - 130px), 100% 100px;
  background-position: top left, left 30px, bottom left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: all 1s ease;  /* just for demo */
}

/* just for demo */
div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
div:hover {
  height: 400px;
}
div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 50%, lightblue 51%), linear-gradient(lightpink, lightpink), linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 50%, lightgreen 51%);
  background-size: 100% 30px, 100% calc(100% - 130px), 100% 100px;
  background-position: top left, left 30px, bottom left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

---

**Using SVG:** <sup>recommended</sup>

This is the approach that I generally recommend and is the best. It involves creating the shape using SVG and then placing it absolutely behind the `div` element.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
polygon {
  fill: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg viewBox='0 0 300 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
    <polygon points='0,10 300,0 300,100 0,75z' />
  </svg>
</div>
```

---

**Using Clip-path:**

Another approach that can be used is to position a pseudo-element behind the main `div` and then set a `clip-path` in the required shape to this pseudo-element.

**Note:** This snippet will currently work only in WebKit powered browsers. Firefox would need the clip-path to be created via SVG element whereas IE doesn't support it all.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}
div:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 5%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 75%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 5%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 75%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I'd +10 for showing more than just one plain way...

Comment: Thank you @Harry this worked perfectly! I went for the SVG method.

Comment: Should already have, cheers once again @Harry

Answer (score 2):

### CSS Perspective

You can use a CSS Perspective Transform to create the shape you want.

```css
div {
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  transform: perspective( 800px ) rotateY( -25deg );
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

- [CSS Tricks Docs](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/)
- [Perspective - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `perspective` to the parent container of the rotated div to give it 3-dimensional depth from the front of the viewport.

---

**N.B.** For the difference between `transform: perspective(value)` and `perspective: value`, see the [CSS Tricks Almanac entry on perspective](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/):

> **Important:** Please note the `perspective` property doesn't affect how the element is rendered; it simply enables a 3D-space for children
>   elements. This is the main difference between the `transform: perspective()` function and the `perspective` property. The first
>   gives element depth while the latter creates a 3D-space shared by all
>   its transformed children.

---

After applying a 3-dimensional depth to the parent container using `perspective`, you can then apply `rotateY` to the `div` you want to rotate.

**Working Example:**

```css
section {
position: relative;
width: 600px;
perspective: 800px;
transform: translateX(-60px);
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
position: absolute;
top:30px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background-color: rgb(235,250,255);
transform: rotateY(320deg);
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 220px;
width: 120px;
height: 140px;
background-color: rgb(103,201,236);
box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px rgba(127,127,127,0.5);
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
position: absolute;
top: 24px;
left: 340px;
width: 120px;
height: 140px;
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px rgba(127,127,127,0.5);
}
```

```html
<section>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</section>
```